# What are the $a\in\Bbb R$ such that there exists a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ with respect to which $f_a$ is represented by the given matrix $M_a$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $M_a=
\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0 \\ 0&a&0 \\ 0&1&3
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $f_a:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ be defined by $f_a(x,y,z)=(ax,a(x+y)+2z,ax-2y+5z).$

What are the values of $a$ such that for some basis $B$ of $\Bbb R^3$, the representative matrix of $f_a$ with respect to $B$ is $M_a$?

---

My idea was that $M=\begin{pmatrix}
a&0&0 \\ a&a&2 \\ a&-2&5
\end{pmatrix}$is the representative matrix of $f_a$ with respect to the canonical basis, and, but I'm not sure about it, we should have $M_a=(M_C^B)^{-1}\cdot M\cdot M_C^B$ where $M_C^B$ is the change of basis matrix from $B$ to the canonical basis $C$ - its columns should be "the vectors of the coordinates of $B$ with respect to $C$", but I'm having problems with this.

I tried to let the columns be $\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} \\ b_{21} \\ b_{31}
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
b_{12} \\ b_{22} \\ b_{32}
\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
b_{13} \\ b_{23} \\ b_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$, and solving for the components, but then what I find is not a basis for any $a$

Comment: For which values of $a$ the Cannonical Jordan Form of $M$ is $M_a$?

Comment: $M_a$ has eigenvalue $a$ and $3$, which counts double. A quick calculation reveals that $M$ has the same eigenvalues only if $a=1$. Does that help?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: That means $M_a$_can_ be similar only if $a=1$, and then one may confirm $M_1$ _is_ similar to $M$ because $\operatorname{rk}(M-\lambda_i I)=\operatorname{rk}(M_1-\lambda_i I) $ for $i=1,2,3$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Correct?